# How to check the current environment of Salesforce

Tags: apex, webservices

I am writing a page to reset password for end users. In that page, the end user is supposed to remember their old password in order to proceed. So I used the below code to check whether their old password is correct or not:

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://' + LOGIN_DOMAIN + '.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/22.0');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
    request.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
    request.setBody(buildSoapLogin(username,oldPassword));

    //basically if there is a loginResponse element, then login succeeded; else there
    //  would be soap fault element after body
    final Boolean verified = (new Http()).send(request).getBodyDocument().getRootElement()
      .getChildElement('Body','http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
      .getChildElement('loginResponse','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com') != null;
```

The problem with this one is currently I am using 'test' as LOGIN_DOMAIN's value as I am currently working on a Sandbox. It is working fine but things would change when moving into production. Is there any way to tell which environment I am working in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sandbox are on "cs*" and production are not. So you can use this to determine if you are on sandbox or production

```
if(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost().left(2).equalsignorecase('cs')){
    System.debug('### Sandbox');
}else{
    System.debug('### prodution');
}
```

I would recommend you put this in custom setting and make it configurable because some time we need to check the from one production org to other sandbox org.